# Eclipse Neon.3 change colors in type hierarchy/call hierarchy

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-neon, call-hierarchy

Is it possible to change the font colors in the type/call hierarchy? Working with C++ Code including several namespaces like

```
a::b::c::d::e::atlastmymethodname() : type
```

it is hard to determine quickly the name of the method if namespaces and method name are in the same color. Printing the namespaces and method name in different colours would be convenient.

Comment: In Eclipse 2019-03 (probably also in the old version you use): _Window > Preferences: C/C++ > Editor > Syntax Coloring_.

Comment: I don't mean the syntax coloring in the editor itself but in the windows "Type Hierarchy" and "Call Hierarchy".

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way to do this. It does sound like a useful enhancement, and I would encourage you to [file an issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) for it.

It's also a fairly easy enhancement to implement, so if you're interested in [contributing to Eclipse CDT](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/contributing), this would make a good first bug, and I would be happy to mentor you through it.